# Force field not affecting falling rigid body in motion

Tags: animation, particles, rigid-body-simulation, force-fields

I am trying to use a force field to affect a falling rigid body mesh. The mesh is falling in a direct line on the Z axis and yet when it passes through the force field, it proceeds unaffected, no matter the strength, size, flow, or type of force.

Note that the falling mesh is also emitting particles. Any ideas on what's wrong? I'm using Blender 2.92. Thanks in advance.

Comment: hello, could you please share your file? make it as simple as possible and use https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: No matter the strength etc., are you sure? For example when I set _Wind_ to a strength of 50, I still reduce the weight of a cube to 0.01 kg to see some noticeable effect - but the spawned particles are getting blown away instantly.

Comment: @GordonBrinkmann you're right -- my object was at 1kg which was why increasing the strength was not effective. Thanks!

Comment: @JS_JS Yes right, just put a box of 1 kg on a table and wait for the wind to push it down ;)

Answer (score 0):

Just increase the strength.

In my example file i have a wind strength of 2000. Just moved and rotated the wind so that you can see the effect.

The cube (rigid body) is falling straight the z-axis. Just an active rigid body - no changes made.

Result:

[image]

[image]